# How to parse host out of a string in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a Postgres (actually Redshift) equivalent to [Hive's parse_url(..., 'HOST')](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions).

[Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/test-parser.html) say it has a URL parser as part of its full text search.  This blog post has [a regex](http://www.jourlin.com/post/2011/07/19/A-PostgreSQL-query-to-extract-a-domain-name-from-a-URL) which may or may not be bulletproof.  What is best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you weren't using Redshift, I'd say "use PL/Perlu, PL/Python, or one of the other procedural languages to get a regular URL parser". Since you're on a proprietary fork of Pg 8.1 you're going to have to settle for a hacky regexp I suspect.

There is no way to access the full-text search URL parser from the SQL level. You could write a C extension to expose the function to SQL quite easily, but of course you can't install the extension in Redshift, so again it won't do you any good.

Time to abuse regular expressions.

(BTW, thanks for actually saying you're on redshift; too many people say "PostgreSQL" when they mean "a vaguely PostgreSQL based hosted version of ParAccel")

Comment: FYI, someone also suggested applying the Hive function on the import into Redshift to pre-compute it into a different field.

Comment: @dfrankow Sure, but you wanted something to do it *in* the DB. If the space cost isn't a concern then pre-splitting the URL into separate fields would be ideal.

Comment: The regular expression functions of PostgreSQL are not supported in Redshift but there is enough in the string operations to enable parsing a host. See my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Redshift now has a [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) function:

It searches for the regular expression in the string and returns the first substring that matches. One example of a regex to extract the host:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '[^/]+\\.[^/:]+') from my_table;
```

Comment: Nice regex fu! A range of characters that doesn't include a slash, followed by a period, followed by another range of characters that doesn't include a slash or semicolon.

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('http://www.google.com/foo?a=b', '[^/]+\\.[^/:]+')` => `{"regexp_substr"=>"http"}` (on a redshift cluster)

Comment: To also remove an optional "www." you could adjust it:
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '[^/(www.)]+\\.[^/:]+') as hostname from my_table

Comment: Is the ":" necessary? In which cases will it return incorrect values?

Answer (score 9):

Until Redshift starts supporting the regular expression functions of PostgreSQL, if you want to get the host out of an HTTP/S URL in Redshift SQL you'll have to do something like:

```
select split_part(url, '/', 3) as host from my_table
```