# SPLIT_PART() not returning results in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

There are strings in a Redshift database that I'm trying to parse. The strings look like this in the `object` field:

yada \n foobar\n thisthing: xyz\nvegetable: amazing

The value I'm trying to get at is `xyz`.

I'm trying:

```
SELECT split_part(v.object::varchar,'\n',3) as first_parse
FROM table_name as v
```

Believing that will return `thisthing: xyz` which I can then split again on ': '.

The Redshift documentation makes me think that's valid Redshift SQL:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html

This answer on StackOverflow also makes me believe this is valid Redshift SQL:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20811724/1807668

However the results of that query are results that are blank in the `first_parse` field (not NULL, actually blank).

How should I go about getting to the `xyz` part of my sample string above using Redshift SQL? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of v.object column?

Comment: I suspect it is because improper data type conversion, could you try v.object::varchar(100)?